# LinearLayout - How to get text to be on the right of an icon?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Bit of a newbie when it comes to android, only been working on it properly for a few days but even after all the searching I've done im stumped and nobody seems to know how to help me. I have this so far:

http://img263.imageshack.us/i/sellscreen.jpg

How can I move the text to be besides each icon rather than underneath it? Hoping the gallery won't be moved either. Here is the code i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/test_image"
     android:src="@drawable/icon"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView  
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="The offcial UK driving theory test application. Over 190 questions."
     />

    <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/test_image"
     android:src="@drawable/icon"

     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView  
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="The offcial UK driving theory test application. Over 190 questions."/>

    <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/test_image"
     android:src="@drawable/icon"

     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView  
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="The offcial UK driving theory test application. Over 190 questions."/>

    <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/test_image"
     android:src="@drawable/icon"

     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView  
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="The offcial UK driving theory test application. Over 190 questions."/>

    <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/test_image"
     android:src="@drawable/icon"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

    <TextView  
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="The offcial UK driving theory test application. Over 190 questions."
        />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Top half of my code doesn't seem to be showing for some reason but it's just the opening of the linear layout.
I will be forever grateful to anyone that can help, i've been racking my brains for days and getting nowhere. Really getting stressed out by it. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap each ImageView/TextView pair in a linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/test_image"
     android:src="@drawable/icon"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView  
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="The offcial UK driving theory test application. Over 190 questions."
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

It's also pretty clear that you didn't ask anyone who knew android, because this is pretty trivial.

Comment: I think people are just lazy since i posted it on two android forums. Oh well so much for racking my brains on it when it was fixed in a second, Thank you very very much!

Comment: @RED_: Sure thing. But also consider @Mayra's answer. I'm not certain that using a relative layout in THIS SPECIFIC CASE will be more efficient, but it's generally better practice to use relative layouts than deeply nested linear layouts.

Comment: Yeah makes sense, RelativeLayouts confuse the hell of me at the moment. How to get everything in the right place is the main thing but i'm sure i'll pick it up the more i have at it.

Comment: The key to relative layouts is that they're drawn in the order that they're declared. So if the first thing in your relative layout has fill_parent for one of the attributes, it will fill the parent regardless of what's left. but if you put a button or a a textview first, and then an item with fill_parent, it will will the remaining space instead of all of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read through the android layout tutorials?  Lots of stuff on the dev site, like [declaring layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html), [common layout objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html), and the [hello views](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/index.html) tutorials.

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, depending on your goals.

Is it a list of items of unknown size that may want to scroll?  Use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).  You can provide a custom layout to the `ListView` with your things side by side.

Do you have a finite set of things?  Use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html).  Tell each `TextView` to layout below the one above, and each `ImageView` to layout to the right of it's `TextView`.

You could also accomplish that with nested `LinearLayouts`, one vertical and a bunch of horizontal, but that is less efficient than using a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: `but that is less efficient than using a RelativeLayout` Are you sure about that? I'm not disagreeing, but a nest of 3 layouts doesn't seem all that expensive.

Comment: When you're dealing with devices with limited power and running off a battery, why would you want to do things the slow way when you can just as easily make it more efficient?  It's one thing if it was an elaborate and complicated thing to save a few cycles, but using a relative layout isn't hard in any way.

Comment: Its definitely less efficient, but if I don't know by how much.  Commonsware had a big post on it, that I can't locate right now, but this post shows the basic idea of why: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html

Comment: @vinay Pai: Are you talking to me or Mayra? What are you saying is less efficient than what? And what makes you able to make that claim?

Comment: I was agreeing with Mayra, based on exactly the same article he/she posted it (I was actually trying to find it again and noticed the recent comment).  It strongly doubt that the difference is very large... but as I said... why so something slightly slower when you can do something faster just as easily?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, im aware that a RelativeLayout is much more effcient having read the tutorials but im still learning that (mostly how to position everything) so for now im going to stick to the LinearLayout. Very small program as it is so doubt it will have an effect. Very much a newbie and i'll just get the basics covered before i move on.